# Why am I getting a blank screen by running my py and kv script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

When I start the program it gives me a blank, black screen. I used the python file for the functionality and the kv file for the properties of the objects. 
Py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class FloatLayoutApp(App):   

    def build(self):
        return FloatLayout()

FlApp = FloatLayoutApp()
FlApp.run()
```

kv file:

```
<CustButton@Button>:
    font_size: 32
    color: 0, 0, 0, 1
    size: 150, 50
    background_normal: ""
    background_down: "bg-grey.jpg"
    background_color: .88, .88, .88, 1
    size_hint: .4, .3

<FloatLayout>:
    CustButton:
        text: "Top Left"
        pos_hint: {"x": 0, "top": 0}
    CustButton:
        text: "Bottom Left"
        pos_hint: {"right": 1, "y": 0}
    CustButton:
        text: "Top Right"
        pos_hint: {"right": 1, "top": 1}
    CustButton:
        text: "Bottom Left"
        pos_hint: {"left": 1, "bottom": 0}
    CustButton:
        text: "Center"
        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0, "center_y": 0}
```

Comment: what is the name of your .kv?, I get https://imgur.com/a/B7DJJEj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a black / blank screen because in the build method it is returning a FloatLayout widget as the root and there are no widgets added to the root.

[Kv language » How to load KV](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#how-to-load-kv)

> There are two ways to load Kv code into your application:
>
> **By name convention:**
>
> Kivy looks for a Kv file with the same name as your App class in
>   lowercase, minus “App” if it ends with ‘App’ e.g:
>
> ```
> MyApp -> my.kv
> ```
>
> If this file defines a Root Widget it will be attached to the App’s
>   root attribute and used as the base of the application widget tree.
>
> **By Builder:**  You can tell Kivy to directly load a string or a file. If this string or file defines a root widget, it will be
>   returned by the method:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_file('path/to/file.kv')
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> Builder.load_string(kv_string)
> ```

## Solution

There are a few solutions to the problem.

### Method 1

Rename your kv file to `floatlayout.kv`

### Method 2

### kv file

Replace class rule, `<FloatLayout>:` with root rule, `FloatLayout:`

### Python Script

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.lang import Builder`
2. Replace `return FloatLayout()` with `return Builder.load_file('kv-filename.kv')`

## Output

[image: Img01 - Method 1]
[image: Img02 - Method 2]